How to forward a single email (by id) from Office365 using Graph-API
I have PowerShell set up to read and process emails.
However, our production process got a strange error, so I want to forward the email to myself to see what is wrong with the attachment.
If have the message ID of the email, along with all the logic to connect with tokens etc...
For example, I can do this:
$result = Get-MgUserMessage -UserId $email -Filter "IsRead eq false"

How do I forward just one particular email based on the ID.  Do I get it then use a Forward method?
I tried this, and don't see any Forward method:

I've searched this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/?view=graph-powershell-1.0
but cannot find the word "forward".

Are you getting an array?  Try using $result[0]

You can use Invoke-MgForwardUserMessage from Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions module
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

$params = @{
    comment = "FYI"
    toRecipients = @(
        @{
            emailAddress = @{
                address = '{your_email}'
            }
        }
    )
}

Invoke-MgForwardUserMessage -UserId $email -MessageId $messageId -BodyParameter $params

Forward message

I had to install that module, before I was using only: Microsoft.Graph.Mail
But now I'm getting:  Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257113/powerhsell-import-modulemicrosoft-graph-users-actions-could-not-load-file-or-a for the Azure.Core issue

@NealWalters I will check it. AFAIK Graph PowerShell SDK is quite buggy
