PowerShell Import-ModuleMicrosoft.Graph.Users.Actions : Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.35.0.0
I was using "Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Mail", and someone suggested using "Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions" so I could use the :Invoke-MgForwardUserMessage" commandlet.
I ran this and it verified:
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions -Scope AllUsers
Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

Then when I got the above error I also tried this:
Install-Module -Name Az 
Uninstall-AzureRm

But when I do this:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions

I get this error:
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've seen other posts talking about updating web.config "bindingRedirect", but since I'm in PowerShell, I could do that in machine.config; but it seems like if I installed everything correctly, just today, I would be having that issue.
If I run this:
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser
Uninstall-AzureRm

and don't close the PowerShell ISE program, then I get these errors:
on the import:
WARNING: Selected Microsoft Graph profile 'v1.0' does not exist for module 'Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions'. No cmdlets were loaded.

and on the Invoke-MgForward get this:
The term 'Invoke-MgForwardUserMessage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check th
e spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

So why would I have Azure problems with Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions but not with Microsoft.Graph.Mail.  We have been using Microsoft.Graph.Mail for a while to automate emails from some of our trading partners.

Get-Module Microsoft.Graph | Update-Module should solve your issue. Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions probably has a dependency on another graph module, i.e. Microsoft.Graph.Users and the version of that one is lower than the version of .Actions. If you want to avoid this kind of problems just avoid the cmdlets on the graph module and make direct API calls using Invoke-MgGraphRequest

Thanks, but Get-Module Microsoft.Graph | Update-Module - didn't help.  I will try your other approach later; for now I got the user to send me her copy of the email.

All right. For ref. the API called by that cmdlet is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0 in case you want to do a direct call to it. Syntax would look very similar.
